# Create incrementing value

Tags: sas, increment

I am trying to create a simple dataset of only 1 column. The values in the column will be "Name1","Name2","Name3",etc... to "Name15". This is the code I have tried:

```
data names;
    drop i;
    length Name $15;
    do i=1 to 15;
        Name=cats("Name",i);
    end;
run;
```

But all this does is print my final name, Name15. I know this is a simple fix but for some reason I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to OUTPUT explicitly.

```
data names;
    drop i;
    length Name $15;
    do i=1 to 15;
        Name=cats("Name",i);
OUTPUT;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew there was something small I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
data name;
   retain Name1-Name15 1;
   stop;
   run;
proc transpose name=name data=name out=name;
   run;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data names;
    drop i;
    length Name $15;
    do i=1 to 15;
        Name=cats("Name",i);
        output;
    end;
run;
```

hmmmmm ... same answer as Haikuo Bian :-(

Comment: Yep. Same answer and it's already accepted. So why have you decided to post this...?